# Winding numbers in complex analysis and Cauchy-Goursat theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, cauchy-integral-formula, winding-number

[image]

I don't understand where the cauchy goursat theorem is used and if it is at the underlined place then why is it used there because the function is not holomorphic at z0.
B. r z0 represents a circle of radius r around and the delta means the boundary [image]

Comment: Are we all supposed to know what formula (5.3) is?

Comment: It's the winding number formula as per my understanding. I have made an edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer. 
The key is to take the integral of the domain with the circle around z0 removed that's why the integral is 2pi and not zero because this is a corollary of the cauchy goursat theorem.

Answer (score 1):

Define$$\begin{array}{rccc}\eta\colon&[0,2\pi]&\longrightarrow&\mathbb C\\&t&\mapsto&z_0+re^{it}.\end{array}$$Then the paths $\gamma$ and $\eta$ are homotopic and therefore, by the Cauchy-Goursat theorem (by this I mean theorem 1.10.7 from [these notes](http://www.math.ust.hk/~machiang/5030/notes/Chap1_ii..pdf)),$$\int_\gamma\frac{\mathrm dz}{z-z_0}=\int_\eta\frac{\mathrm dz}{z-z_0}.$$

Comment: The cauchy goursat theorem as stated in the text has the premises that if f is holomorphic on A and continuous on the boundary of A  then the integral over the boundary is 0

Comment: Can you please tell me what I am missing?

Comment: No, I cannot, since I don't have access to your textbook.

Comment: Can you tell me if the above statement is correct?

Comment: The statement from your first comment? Yes, it is correct.

Comment: Is 1/(z-z0) holomorphic in A?

Comment: Of course not: it is undefined at $z_0$.

Comment: Then how can we use the cauchy goursat theorem?

Comment: I have no idea. I would prove it using theorem 1.10.7 from [these notes](http://www.math.ust.hk/~machiang/5030/notes/Chap1_ii..pdf).

Comment: So is your answer still correct?

Comment: Yes, since that's what I used in my answer. But I shall edit it.

Comment: Can you also please up vote the question so that more people can see the it?

Comment: I've done it, but it was mostly because I was upset by the fact that someone downvoted it.